# $a \in A$ is equivalent to $ \{ a \} \subset A $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

In *Naive Set theory* by Halmos, he states $a \in A$ is equivalent to $ \{ a \} \subset A $. I am guessing that here he means logically equivalent. Intuitively, I see how they can be interchanged, but I am not sure how to prove it.

I attempted to set up a truth table. I tried breaking down $B \subset A$ into the sentence $ \forall x(x \in B \implies x \in A) $.

I know that truth tables in predicate logic would be infinitely long, but I thought that in this special case, since we only have $\{ a \}$ I could employ a truth table with $B = \{ a \}$ and $x = a$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
  a \in A & a \in B & \implies & a \in A\\ \hline
\bf{T} & T & \bf{T} & T \\ \hline
\bf{T} & F & \bf{T} & T\\ \hline
\bf{F} & T & \bf{F} & F\\ \hline
F & F & T & F\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This truth table shows that these are not logically equivalent. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting at something along the lines of $ \{ a, a, a,... \} $

Comment: No. Since $a$ is the only element, $b=a$ necessarily. At least intuitively.

Comment: So where in my attempt did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You went wrong in assuming that this is a logical equivalence. It is not; set-theoretically they are equivalent, but logically they are not, as you yourself  demonstrated.

Specifically, $a \in \{ a \}$ has to be true set-theoretically (and hence the last two rows of the truth-table do not apply), but it is not a logical truth.

Put a different way: once you assume some basic axioms regarding set-theory (in particular ones that *define* the notion of subset ... or what something like a singleton set means) you can derive $\{ a \} \subset A$ from $a \in A$, and vice versa. But without those axioms, you cannot. So that shows that these are not logically equivalent, but 'merely' equivalent in the context of set-theory.

Comment: But $ a \in A $ is not a set and neither is $ \{ a \} \subset A $. These are sentences, right? So how can we talk about set-equivalent?

Comment: Oh just saw your edit, but my questions still stands.

Comment: @pmac Yes, they are statements. What I mean is that the statement $a \in \{ a \}$ *has* to be true in the context of set-theory, whereas from the perspective of pure logic one can set it to false.